# How can I pass router parameters to import statement in Vue?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-router, webpack-4

I have route rule:

```
{
    path: ':something/:category/index',
    name: 'index',
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "[request]" */ `@module/${category???}/index.vue`)
  }
```

how can I pass the `category` var to use inside the `import` function?